# using replace to clean up select-string input

Tags: regex, parsing, powershell, replace

I am parsing logs and grabbing output, but I want to clean up the out put. currently I am getting the full path of the log file in the output which is long and not needed. The code below is what I am trying to use, but I am getting an error that my replace is not a valid regular expression.

```
select-string $_ -pattern "gam.exe : Error 409: Entity already exists" -context 1,0 | ForEach-Object{$_ -replace "D:\test1\user\mail\mail-Load\logs","" }
```

I am not sure what I need to do to get the input for replace right, do I need to escape characters?

Comment: Have you tried using single quotes instead of double?

Comment: I just did, but it did not seem to change the error. it does not like "D:\test1\user\mail\mail-Load\logs","" or 'D:\test1\user\mail\mail-Load\logs',""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslash is the regex escape character.  To use it as part of a literal match in the regex, it must be escaped with another backslash.  If you're not sure what characters need to be escaped, [regex] has an escape method you can use that will escape all the reserved characters for you:

```
[regex]::escape("D:\test1\user\mail\mail-Load\logs")
D:\\test1\\user\\mail\\mail-Load\\logs
```

So

```
 'D:\\test1\\user\\mail\\mail-Load\\logs'
```

is the regex you would use to match the literal string

```
'D:\test1\user\mail\mail-Load\logs'
```

Comment: that worked, I just needed to escape the \ and it is now filtering properly. Thank you